# Multiple radio groups in a foreach loop

Tags: php, html, loops, radio-button

I have two loops, a `for` loop that stores iterations in an array, and a `foreach` loop that iterates through the array, assigning radio groups to each iteration value:

```
<?php
$current_val = array();
for($i = 0; $i <= 10; ++$i){
    $current_val[$i] = $i;
}

foreach($current_val as $key => $val):?>
    <div id="radio_group_<?php echo $val;?>">
        <input type="radio" name="name" value="<?php echo $val;?>"/>Name
        <input type="radio" name="address" value="<?php echo $val;?>"/>Address
        <input type="radio" name="phone" value="<?php echo $val;?>"/>Phone
    </div>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

This prints:

```
<div id="radio_group_0">
    <input type="radio" name="name" value="0"/>Name
    <input type="radio" name="address" value="0"/>Address
    <input type="radio" name="phone" value="0"/>Phone
</div>
<div id="radio_group_1">
    <input type="radio" name="name" value="1"/>Name
    <input type="radio" name="address" value="1"/>Address
    <input type="radio" name="phone" value="1"/>Phone
</div>

etc..
```

What I'd like is for users to only be allowed to select one radio per group and one radio per name, so two levels of selection restriction.  As of now, users can only select one radio per name but can still select multiple radios per group.  Is there a way to do this with HTML/PHP, can I somehow assign two names to a radio?  I was also thinking of nesting forms, but I'd rather not as I don't think that is valid XHTML markup.

Comment: don't use the same id twice, ids should be unique to each html element

Comment: I changed the group id from `radio_group` to `radio_group_$val`, now how can I restrict selection within each group if radios have different names?

Comment: you can use jquery for that. make a function that'd be called when any radio button is selected and iterate through all radio buttons and set property checked false except the one which has called the event.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like I'll have to resort to js or run validation with php on form submit.

Comment: Why don't you swap _value_ and _name_?